# How to disable an extension for VS2017 but enable for VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility, vsixmanifest

I have created a ".vsix" package . I have updated the manifest file with 
`"InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[15.0,)"`

The command used to install the ".vsix" file is 
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" /a /q "C:\ccrc.vsix"`

But still the extension gets installed for vs2017.

Any way to disable the extension for vs2017, but keep it enabled for vs2019

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly enabled VS 2017 which is version 15. VS 2019 is version 16. Change your manifest to:

```
"InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[16.0,)"
```

Comment: Changed the manifest to 
<B>"InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[16.0,)" </B>

Updated the ".vsix" file and installed using the command 
<B>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" /a /q "C:\ccrc.vsix"</B>

But still the extension gets reflected in the VS2017

Comment: Did you uninstall the extension from VS 2017 from the previous installation before you installed the new VSIX?

Comment: I got the issue fixed. In addition to manifest file, there are two json files "catalog.json" and "manifest.json". In the two json files, I updated the 15.0 to 16.0, created a new ".vsix" file and installed it.